# ASP.NET FormView DetailsView and polymorphism

Tags: asp.net, .net, detailsview, formview

I'm writing an ASP.NET Master Page that does the common grunt work for master/detail editing (ValidationSummary, error handling, popup of detail view using jQuery-ui dialog).  It has two `ContentPlaceHolder` controls for the master and detail views, the master placeholder is expected to contain a `GridView`, and the detail placeholder either a `DetailsView` or a `FormView`.

The master page just needs to access a few basic members of the DetailsView or FormView:

- ChangeMode method
- DataBind method
- CurrentMode property
- InsertItem method
- UpdateItem method

I was surprised to see that, while both DetailsView and FormView have these same members, they are not (except DataBind) inherited from a common base class or interface.  There are even two equivalent enums `FormViewMode` and `DetailsViewMode`, so that the ChangeMode and CurrentMode members don't even have the same signature.

I am intending to get round this by creating a wrapper class, but can anyone explain why they are implemented like this?  Am I storing up trouble by attempting to use them polymorphically?

I find it hard to believe that this was not deliberate on the part of Microsoft's engineers, so I can only conclude that they intended to discourage polymorphic use.

Answer (score 0):

> while both DetailsView and FormView have these same members, they are
>   not inherited from a common base class or interface.

Yes they are:

DetailsView : CompositeDataBoundControl, IDataItemContainer, INamingContainer, ICallbackContainer, ICallbackEventHandler, IPostBackEventHandler, IPostBackContainer, IDataBoundItemControl, IDataBoundControl, IFieldControl

FormView : CompositeDataBoundControl, IDataItemContainer, INamingContainer, IPostBackEventHandler, IPostBackContainer, IDataBoundItemControl, IDataBoundControl, IRenderOuterTableControl

Comment: I meant that the members I listed (with the exception of DataBind of course) are not inherited from a common base class or interface.

Comment: I don't believe the Microsoft engineers are out to "discourage polymorphic use".  Perhaps when you try to create your wrapper case you'll discover the reasons they decided not to make every function/enum inherited.